# Authorization between nuxtjs and the backend API

Tags: authentication, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a [Vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) application created using [Nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide). I am also using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) as the backend server, and I made an API to interact with the backend server (Django) and front-end app (Vuejs/Nuxtjs). And any API related fetch are done in the `AsyncData function` of the page to render the data on the server-side using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/axios). Also, I am using json web token authentication, and the API generates a jwt token after successful login which is stored in the cookie. So on the backend, it will always check for the request's authorization header for the token. If the request is from a logged in user (authorized token) then return authenticated json data, or else return non authenticated data.

*The problem:*

When the user navigates to the app, I would like to check if the user is authenticated. If the user is authenticated, render the authenticated page. If not then display non authenticated page.

*My thoughts:*

When the fetch is done from the App on the `AsyncData function`, I would check whether there is any value for the cookie. If there is then send the token with the request's authorization header. But, since the page will be rendered on the server first, and not on the client side (where the cookie actually is) it will never find the token for the authorization.

How can I check if the user is already logged in or not so that I can get authenticated and non authenticated data respectively from the API?

**Update**

When I successfully log in (post authorized email and password), I get a json response back with the token, which I set in the cookie like this:

```
this.$cookie.set('my_auth_token', this.token, {expires: 15})
```

How can I retrieve client side cookie and into the nuxt server for server side rendering?

Comment: when the user first login you can save the token into the user's browser into the [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and everytime the user load your app you can check for the token in the user's browser `localstorage` if the token exist's then you can send `GET` to check if the token is valid

Comment: @AmrAly Hi! I have updated my question of how I am actually retrieving the token and setting it in the cookies or localstorage will also work. What I am confused is how can I get the client side cookie into the nuxt server for server side rendering?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I've searched for your problem but unfortunately Authentication in SSR is a new hot topic and there is no an easy guide for implementing it - as far as i know - but i would be appreciated if you share with us any information for how to implement this.

Comment: When you make a request from the browser to the server, the cookies are included into the request headers, so you should be able to just get and use them on the server.

Comment: Have this problem solved?@BenjaminSmithMax

Comment: @soarinblue I ended up getting the cookies from the request headers. This [blog](https://medium.com/@eddybordi/nuxt-js-ssr-authentication-8a6afba26533) helped me.

Answer (score 2):

> Cookies are exposed in the (Express) Nuxt server through [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware).

Specifically, they can be read from the `req.headers.cookie` property. You can see an example implementation of this in the [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-routes).

Regarding your implementation: fetching the privileged data from your API using Node would seem to be the ideal way to delegate session handling to that single service (rather than both) and provide SSR for your users.

If you've chosen to instead implement your session handling on the Django service then you'll need to "forward" your cookies by passing them into your `axios` request headers.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using Firebase authentication. There is an [example project](https://github.com/rossma/nuxt-firebase-auth-ex) on Github as well as [a blog entry](http://monstersandwich.blogspot.co.uk/2018/02/vuejs-nuxtjs-vuex-firebase-persisted.html) outlining the important files and configuration used in the application.